# How to expand combinations formula?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How to expand $\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ to $\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}$?

I've seen many proofs of binomial expansion where they assume that both equations are true. But they never explain how they jump to that second form of combinations formula?

What's the way to expand that?

Comment: Note that:$$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!} = \frac{n (n-1) (n-2) \ldots (n-k+1) \color{blue}{(n-k) (n-k-1) \ldots}}{\color{blue}{(n-k)(n-k-1))\ldots}}$$

Comment: By the way, welcome to Math.SE. Take the opportunity to take the [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour), if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on [how to ask](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), on [formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and on writing down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really understand how does n! expand to that.

Comment: "*I don't really understand how does n! expand to that.*"  To answer that, I remind you that for natural number $n$ you have that $n!$ is **defined** as $n!=n\times (n-1)\times (n-2)\times \cdots \times 3\times 2\times 1$.  You might also see it defined as $n!=\prod\limits_{k=1}^n k$ or defined recursively as $0!=1!=1$ and $n!=n\times (n-1)!$ for each $n>1$.  If you instead defined $n!$ as the number of bijective functions from a finite set with $n$ elements to itself, then from there you can show that it is equivalent to the other definitions that I give here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$n!$ is defined as:

$n!  = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdots (n-2) \cdot (n-1) \cdot n$ $=\prod_{i = 1}^n i$

Now consider the following example of a simple case

[image]

Which can also be written as:

[image]

Now come to the general case:

$$(n-0)(n-1)(n-2)\cdots\left(n-(k-1)\right) = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} = n^{\underline k}$$

Similarly for your equation:

$$\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k(k-1)(k-2)\cdots 1}=  \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!} = \binom {n}{k} = \frac{n^{\underline k}}{k!}$$

It's just using the definition of $n!$ and simple division of integers.

More information [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) 
[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Applications)

Comment: It is worth keeping the reference to $n\frac{k}{~}$ and including a link to the wikipedia page for [falling factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) as this is not uncommon notation to encounter.  It might not appear in elementary textbooks all of the time, but it is still useful notation and finds its use frequently beyond the elementary courses.

Comment: @JMoravitz I thought he might not be familiar with that notation, so can cause confusion to fairly simple topic.